# Q: SlidingDrawer is Not Scrolling Up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, slidingdrawer

My SlidingDrawer is working but not Scrolling Up enough. Handle when come to bottom of the "MENÜYE DÖN" button, stopping! I can't scroll more.  I know SlidingDrawer is deprecated but I do not know the alternative.

I can see in Preview, SlidingDrawer's border is narrow.

Here is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Sözlük hazırlamanın en güç yanı sözcükleri anlam kayganlığından kurtarma, onları belli bir yere oturtmadır. Bu da ancak Samuel Butler’in dediği gibi onların belirsiz yanlarını söz duvarlarıyla kuşatmakla gerçekleşebilir.
Bu cümledeki altı çizili sözle, sözcüklere yönelik olarak ne yapıldığı anlatılmıştır?"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL0">
    <Button

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="A) Tanımsal sınırlar koyulduğu"
        android:id="@+id/a" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LL2"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="B) Birbirlerinden etkilenişlerinin gösterildiği"
        android:id="@+id/b"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL3">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="C) Çağrışımsal değerlerinin belirtildiği"
        android:id="@+id/c"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL4">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="D) Zenginleştirme yollarının açıklandığı"
        android:id="@+id/d"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL5">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E) Kullanım sıklığının yansıtıldığı"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:id="@+id/e"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menüye Dön"
        android:background="#bababa"
        android:id="@+id/anamenudon"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SlidingDrawer
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:text="==  ÇÖZÜM  =="
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ababab">
            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="150dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CEVAP BURADA"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found! It works perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Sözlük hazırlamanın en güç yanı sözcükleri anlam kayganlığından kurtarma, onları belli bir yere oturtmadır. Bu da ancak Samuel Butler’in dediği gibi onların belirsiz yanlarını söz duvarlarıyla kuşatmakla gerçekleşebilir.
Bu cümledeki altı çizili sözle, sözcüklere yönelik olarak ne yapıldığı anlatılmıştır?"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL0">
    <Button

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="A) Tanımsal sınırlar koyulduğu"
        android:id="@+id/a" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LL2"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="B) Birbirlerinden etkilenişlerinin gösterildiği"
        android:id="@+id/b"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL3">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="C) Çağrışımsal değerlerinin belirtildiği"
        android:id="@+id/c"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL4">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:text="D) Zenginleştirme yollarının açıklandığı"
        android:id="@+id/d"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/LL5">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E) Kullanım sıklığının yansıtıldığı"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button"
        android:id="@+id/e"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menüye Dön"
        android:background="#bababa"
        android:id="@+id/anamenudon"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SlidingDrawer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:text="==  ÇÖZÜM  =="
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ababab"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="10dip">
            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="CEVAP BURADA"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```